# ElasticSearch automatic nested mapping

Tags: elasticsearch

I want to be able to insert documents and preferably map all inner objects to nested ones automatically. Is this possible?

1. My specific use case is that I am collecting documents of the same type that may or may not have the same fields of those currently in the store. So I would prefer if it can just automatically do the nested mapping without me having to tell it to do so.
2. Barring that could I potentially update the index before I insert an object with new fields? And would it be ok if I just set the type of the nested property to nested without specifying the fields of the property?

Code:

```
client.IndicesPutMapping("captures", "capture", new
{

    capture = new
    {
        properties = new
        {
            CustomerInformations = new
            {
                type = "nested",
                //...do not specify inner fields ?
            }
        }

    }
});
```

3. Is partially mappings allowed when overriding mappings. In other words if I have the mapping above will the other properties of the capture objects still be mapped in a default way?

Comment: Were You able to do it so?

Answer (score 1):

For those still struggling with the issue:
https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/20886

The problem has been resolved in V5